# Calling free() after malloc causes unexpected behaviour

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free, c-strings

Hi I read that I should call `free()` as soon as I could do that to free the memory but when I call free in this way my code stops working correctly. what's the problem?

I want to call `free()` in every iteration and when an error occurs.

```
int read_words(char *words[], int size, int max_str_len) {
    int i, j;
    char *ExtendedWord = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < size && size != -1; ++i) {
        char tmp[1], ch, *word = tmp;
        for (j = 0; j < max_str_len; ++j) {
            if (scanf("%c", &ch) == EOF || ch == 'R') {
                size = -1;
                break;
            }
            if (ch == ' ')
                break;
            word[j] = ch;
            ExtendedWord = malloc((i + 2) * sizeof(char));
            if (ExtendedWord == NULL)
                return -1;
            strcpy(ExtendedWord, word);
            word = ExtendedWord;
            free(ExtendedWord);
        }
        word[j] = '\0';
        words[i] = word;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: You assign an invalid address to `words[i]` since you freed it and can't use it anymore.

Comment: so where I should call free?

Answer (score 0):

```
        strcpy(ExtendedWord,word);
```

`strcpy()` expects as 2nd parameter the address of the 1st character of a "C"-string, which in fact is a `char`-array with at least one element being equal to `'\0'`.

The memory `word` points to does not meet such requirements.

Due to this the infamous undefined behaviour is invoked, probably messing up the program's memory management, which in turn causes `free()` to fail.

Comment: Can someone suggest where is the prober location to call free with every iteration?

Comment: @Daniel98: The question is not "*where [...] to call free()*" but how to not avoid to "*mess up the program's memory management*".

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you free the newly allocated block instead of the previous one.
- you so not null terminate the string before passing it to `strcpy`
- `word` should be initialized as `NULL` or to a block of allocated memory, not to point to a local array which you cannot pass to `free()`.
- you should reallocate the array **before** copying the new character at its end.

Here is a modified version:

```
int read_words(char *words[], int size, int max_str_len) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char *word = malloc(1);
        if (word == NULL)
            return -1;
        for (j = 0; j < max_str_len; ++j) {
            int ch;
            char *ExtendedWord;
            if ((ch = getchar()) == EOF || ch == 'R') {
                size = -1;
                break;
            }
            if (ch == ' ' || c == '\n')
                break;
            /* reallocate array for one more character and a null terminator */
            ExtendedWord = malloc(i + 2);
            if (ExtendedWord == NULL)
                return -1;
            memcpy(ExtendedWord, word, i);
            free(word);
            word = ExtendedWord;
            word[j] = ch;
        }
        if (size == -1) {
            free(word);
            break;
        }
        word[j] = '\0';
        words[i] = word;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: why should I null terminate before passing to strcpy? It will just keep copying the other parts which don't affect my code at all?

Comment: `strcpy` requires that the source string be null terminated. Either set the null terminator before passing to `strcpy` or use `memcpy` with the appropriate size as I did in the above code.

Comment: ok and what about you should reallocate the array before copying the new character at its end.
how does this make a difference?

Comment: If you want to use strcpy, you must set the null terminator so the current array is too short for both the new character and the null terminator. You could possibly set the character and use memcpy to copy i+1 bytes to the newly allocated array. It would work only because you increment the size one byte at a time and you also allocate one extra byte for the null terminator. Reallocating before copying is just a more generic approach, that works for any amount of extra data.

Answer (score 0):

> I Read that I should call free() as soon as I could do that to free the memory

That description is a little ambiguous.  It is reasonable only if you interpret "as soon as I could do that" to mean the same as "as soon as I no longer need the allocated memory".

> but when I call free in this way my code stops working correctly. what's the problem?

The problem with respect to `free` is that you free the memory before you are done with it.  Subsequently attempting to access that memory produces undefined behavior.

There are other problems with the code, too, discussed in other answers, but this is how the `free` fits into the picture.

> I want to call free in every iteration and when an error occurs.

Inasmuch as it appears that your function intends to provide pointers to the allocated memory to its caller via the `words` array, you *must not* free that memory anywhere within the scope of the function, because the caller (it must be presumed) intends to use it.  Therefore the caller must assume the responsibility for freeing it.  The function's documentation should clearly describe that responsibility.

Perhaps the confusion arises here:

> ```
>            word=ExtendedWord;
> ```

It is essential to understand that the assignment copies *the pointer*, not the space to which it points.  Afterward, `word` points to the same (dynamically allocated) space that `ExtendedWord` does, so that freeing `ExtendedWord` invalidates both copies of the pointer.